# Observing Multiple NSKeyObservingKeyValueoptions swift

Tags: swift, key-value-observing

How to observe multiple NSKeyObservingKeyValueoptions in swift

```
 self.avplayerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options:[.Initial | .New], context: nil)
```

I get an error like

**Error**

*No '|' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'NSKeyValueObservingOptions'*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
 self.avplayerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options:[.Initial | .New], context: nil)
```

to:

```
 self.avplayerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options:[.Initial, .New], context: nil)
```